# what does the error means in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {     
@ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;
        dashboards: IDashboard[];
        dashboard: IDashboard;    
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _dshboardService: DashboardService, private router: Router) {
                var sesssion = sessionStorage.getItem('EmpDetail');
                var ses = JSON.parse(sesssion);
                var EmpNo = ses[0].EmpNumber;
                var CompanyCode = ses[0].CompanyCode;
                this.dashboard = {};
                this.dashboard.EmpName = ses[0].EmpName;
                this.dashboard.EmpNumber = ses[0].EmpNumber;
            }
}
```

this shows the below error on the line `this.dashboard = {};`

> Error TS2322  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IDashboard'.
>   Property 'EmpName' is missing in type '{}'.

I need to assign the value to the properties of dashboard model and bind the same in html component

Below is my IDashboard:

```
export interface IDashboard {
    EmpName: string,
    EmpNumber: string,
    EmailId: string,
    FirstName: string,
    LastName: string,
    Gender: string,
    Program:string
}
```

Comment: can you show the `IDashboard` class?

Comment: @SurajRao I had updated my Question with `IDashboard` class. Check it now

Answer (score 2):

Error there:

```
this.dashboard = {};
```

this.dashboard has type IDashboard, i guess it has at least one to optional field. So you can't set object without setting this required fields.
Something like:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

const person = {} // Error
const person1 = {name: 'Test'} // No Error


interface Person1 {
 name?: string; //name is optional field
}
 const person = {} // No Error
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare and initialize it with empty object inside the constructor or ngOninit.

You need to have the Dashboard declared in the component as,

```
const dashboard: Dashboard= {  param1: "", param2: ""...etc};
```

Comment: above constructor !

Comment: im getting errors if I add this code above constructor thats why i asked.Following are my error 
Build:A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.
Build:Duplicate identifier 'dashboard'.
Build:Cannot find name 'Dashboard'.

Comment: it's just a sample code have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618181/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-title-of-undefined/47618205#47618205